# Learn Python the Hard Way ex 43 looping issue

Tags: python, class, object, while-loop

I am currently working on this exercise from Learn Python the Hard way and am struggling with a little bit of an issue. Whenever I make it to the 
`LaserWeaponArmory(scene)`portion of my code, it will loop twice prior to executing the actual death scene. Essentially allowing me 20 attempts at guessing the door code as opposed to just 10. It will loop back to the start of the scene prior to the next 10 attempts. After that, it will exit properly.

Objects and classes are starting to make more sense to me, but I am just looking for some pointers in the direction of solving this issue at the moment. I would appreciate any advice anyone has to offer!

I have provided what I believe to be the associated code with my issue below, but I'm still a n00b, so if you need to see more to answer my question please let me know!

```
class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
         print "This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."
         exit(1)

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

            # be sure to print out the last scene
            current_scene.enter()

class Death(Scene):

    quips = [
        "You died. You kind suck at this.",
        "Your mom would be proud...if she were smarter.",
        "Such a luser.",
        "I have a small puppy that's better at this."
    ]

    def enter(self):
        print Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
        exit(1)

class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You do a dive roll into the Weapon Armory, crouch and scan the room"
        print "for more Gothons that might be hiding. It's dead quiet, too quiet."
        print "You stand up and run to the far side of the room and find the"
        print "neutron bomb and it's container. There's a keypad lock on the box"
        print "and you need the code to get the bomb out. If you get the code"
        print "wrong 10 times then lock closes forever and you can't"
        print "get the bomb. The code is 3 digits."
        code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1, 9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
        guesses = 0
        attempt = 1
        print "Attempt number %s." % attempt
        guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")


        while guess != code and guesses != 9:
            print "BZZZZZZEDDD!"
            guesses += 1
            attempt += 1
            print "Attempt number %s." % attempt
            guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")

        if guess == code:
            print "The container clicks open and the seal breaks, letting gas out."
            print "You grab the neutron bomb and run as fast as you can to the"
            print "bridge where you must place it in the right spot."
            return 'the_bridge'
        else:
            print "The lock buzzes one last time and then you hear a sickening"
            print "melting sound as the mechanism is fused together."
            print "You decide to sit there, and finally the Gothons blow up the"
            print "ship from their ship and you die."
            return 'death'
```

Comment: How do you run this example? Can you provide some example of `main()` of how this program should be run. Also is the indentaiton in the while loop correct? it seems as ` if guess == code:` should be indenter more.

Comment: @Marcin Ok, so I think I got the jist of what your asking for, however this is my first time actually talking with anyone else about programming. The program runs using this                                                                                             `a_map = Map('central_corridor')`
`a_game = Engine(a_map)`
`a_game.play()` central_corridor is just another class that calls the scene prior to this. Essentially this is just a little text based game to get me used to playing with objects and classes.

Comment: Also if I include the `if` and `else` statements within the while loop, its starts acting pretty wild. I have already tried that previously.

Comment: [all code from the online book](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html) This page has the entire program on it, you can see everything I am talking about here.

Comment: haha I think I am just as confused about how to ask this question properly as I am about the issue I am having. I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Engine` loop you `enter` each scene twice. The first time is the last line:

```
current_scene.enter()
```

The second time is when you re-enter the loop:

```
next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
```

I think that last line is supposed to be outside the `while` loop. Just un-indent it :)

Comment: @ Brian L Thank you, I had no idea that I had somehow missed that. After reading your answer, it was indeed the solution to this problem. I will keep this in mind going forward! Thanks a lot!